# The "Hide div before scrolling" codes does not work no matter what

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a local website on the **Bitnami Wordpress Stack** with the **Arras theme**, if that's important.

I'm making a fixed menu that I want to show after I have scrolled 190 pixels down on the page. The problem is that anything works, no matter which JQuery or JavaScript code I try. I have searched and searched here on StackOverflow, and I know that this question have been asked numerous times here before - but I have tried every code I could find, and none works. This is my JavaScript/JQuery/HTML/PHP code for my menu, placed in the *header.php* file:

```
<div class="medfolg" id="medfolg">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).bind('scroll', function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 190){
            $('#medfolg').show();
        } else {
            $('#medfolg').hide();
        };
      });
    });
</script>
<?php 
if ( function_exists('wp_nav_menu') ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
        'menu' => 'medfolg',
        'menu_class' => 'sf-menu'
    ) );
}   
?>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS code I have placed in my *default.css* file:

```
#medfolg.medfolg {position:fixed;}
#medfolg  { text-transform: lowercase; position: absolute; top: 0; width: 100%; background: #f5f5f5; z-index:5000; display: none;}
#medfolg .menu-medfolg-container { width: 980px; margin: 0 auto; }
#medfolg .sf-menu { position: relative; top:3px !important; }
#medfolg .sf-menu a  { font-size: 22px; color: #444; margin-right: 15px;}
```

I desperately need some help - please!

**EDIT:** I've made a jsFiddle here with only small modifications (Wordpress .php menu cannot be read on other places than Wordpress): http://jsfiddle.net/wHMjr/

Comment: Try replacing $ with jQuery or try jQuery(document).ready(function($) { .. }...

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Can you please post the full JQuery code so I don't do anything wrong? I'm sorry, I'm not so good at this.

Comment: You should probably provide a more complete example (either a live one or a jsFiddle), as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Tu9Hw/) sketch seems to work just fine (and it is almost exactly the same as yours).

Comment: Thank you so much, @MasterAM - your code was the only one working on both the demo page in IE and Firefox, **and** on the actual site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, I will post my code:

First, the code is wrapped with a self-executing function to prevent conflict between libraries:

```
(function($){
    //code goes here, now $ is a local reference to the jQuery object.
})(jQuery)
```

Then, I create the handler:

```
var setMenuVisibility = function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 190){
        $('#medfolg').show();
    } else {
        $('#medfolg').hide();
    };
}
```

which will be attached to the window's scroll event and change the menu's visibility according to the scroll status.

The attachment is done by binding the function to the event:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', setMenuVisibility);
//and set the initial visibility
setMenuVisibility();
```

The last line in the above section sets the initial state of the menu, as it is possible that the initial scroll value would require it to be visible (e.g, a link to a lower subsection of the page).

The entire process is initiated when the document's markup is ready.

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/masteram/Tu9Hw/1/).

Comment: Thank you very much, @MasterAM. This worked everywhere - I can't upvote you yet because I am new on this site, but I will when I get enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Try using vanilla js instaead of $`(window).scrollTop()` try `window.scrollY > 190`

for the complete function I  would use `toggle` too so:

#### jQuery

```
    //Use jQuery to make sure we are using correct function
    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var el = jQuery('#medfolg');
        if (window.scrollY > 100) {
            el.show(); //Use this to toggle element visibility
        } else {
            el.hide()
        }
    });
```

#### HTML

```
<div style="display:none" id="medfolg">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Inspiration</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wHMjr/1/)

Comment: So you mean like this?: `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.scrollY > 170){
     $('#medfolg').toggle();
    }
  });
 </script>` Still doesn't work... I may be stupid, though.

Comment: @SimenMangseth Updated. Don't worry it has nothing to do with stupidity :)

Comment: Is that the full code? Shouldn't I use the `.toggle` thing, too? I'm so sorry, but I'm really a newbie in JavaScript/JQuery... And thank you for answering at all.

Comment: Sorry @SimenMangseth the answer wasn't clear. I edited. Don't feel bad about asking. Next time you will be able to answer some one else.

Comment: I think you have done a mistake - you have put slashes before the `console.log` line so that the whole line appears as a comment, right? So I edited it to make just the comment a comment. But still it does not work. I begin to wonder that it has something to do with some of the other things not working, like JQuery not functioning at all, or my CSS, the Bitnami local web server or something wrong about Wordpress...

Comment: I commented out the whole thing since you don't really need it. 
try posting jsfiddle.net with the whatever isn't working Also check your console for errors. I jQuery wasn't loaded you would have known

Comment: I've set up a JSFiddle here, but that does not work either: http://jsfiddle.net/wHMjr/ I must do something wrong.

Comment: don't use `toggle`, see my comment to the original post.

Comment: @SimenMangseth See the demo.

Comment: Thank you so much! This **works in Firefox, but not in IE** (haven't tested Chrome). Do you have a Internet Explorer-fix? It does not have to work in IE6-8, but if it worked for IE9-11, it would be great.

Comment: Try switching back to $(window).scrollTop()

Comment: Thanks! The demo now works in both IE and Firefox - but now it stopped working on Firefox on the actual page, and it still don't work on the actual page in IE, either. So it works in the demo on both browsers, but doesn't work on the actual site, even with the exact same CSS and script. But then I tried the code @MasterAM sent me as a comment above (http://jsfiddle.net/Tu9Hw/), and that was the only one working both as a demo **and** on the actual site!